# Split a column of string then group by the index and then add them up?

Tags: python, pandas

so here is what I have in my dataframe

```
+--------+------------------+---------------------+--+
| Userid |      Country     |        food         |  |
+--------+------------------+---------------------+--+
|   1001 |  United States   | cheese;burger;pizza |  |
|   1002 | United States    | burger;pizza        |  |
|   1003 | Canada           | pizza;noodles       |  |
+--------+------------------+---------------------+--+
```

I need to make them into this way, i tried different ways,like making them into dictionary,but not works...

```
+---------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
|    Country    | Cheese | Burger | pizza | noodles |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
| United States |      1 |      2 |     2 |       0 |
| Canada        |      0 |      0 |     1 |       1 |
+---------------+--------+--------+-------+---------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this using the `.str`, string accessor, and `get_dummies`, then `groupby` 'Country' column and `sum`:

```
df['food'].str.get_dummies(';').groupby(df['Country']).sum()
```

Output:

```
               burger  cheese  noodles  pizza
Country                                      
Canada              0       0        1      1
United States       2       1        0      2
```

With `reset_index`:

```
df['food'].str.get_dummies(';').groupby(df['Country']).sum().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         Country  burger  cheese  noodles  pizza
0         Canada       0       0        1      1
1  United States       2       1        0      2
```

Comment: @JoyceHong You're welcome.  Be safe and stay healthy.